# Iterate Markers in JavaScript Array vs List

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

In this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ckf9d1pz/), why is it that I can iterate over `neighborhoods[iterate]` but not when marker `position` is set to `latLng`?

Try both in line 36. When it's set to `neighborhood[iterate]`, the markers drop fine. But when it is set to `latLng`, they all drop in the same position. I reckon this is related to iteration.

```
markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latLng, //[iterator],
```

I built this example from various examples from Google Maps documentation. How can I fix this? I would prefer to use `latLng` because it's easier to organize if more information needs to be added. Is that called a JavaScript list? And `neighborhoods` is a JavaScript array?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a scope issue in the call to `addMarker()`.

**[Here is an example fix in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/87463gvx/)**

#### Fix some code

Referencing the function directly and binding to the index value of the call will help with the issue.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < markersList.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(addMarker.bind(this, i), i * 200);
}
```

Change the function to access the correct index.

```js
function addMarker(i) {
    var data = markersList[i]
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.latLng[0], data.latLng[1]);
    markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLng,
        map: map,
        draggable: false,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
    }));
}
```

Comment: You will have to modify some for when you change categories, but this gets you started.